# How to seek in video asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show my video to HTML. I am trying to use this code.
it's okay but I can not seek video. 
how can I solve this problem?

```
      HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test2.mp4");

        var objFile = new FileInfo(strVideoFilePath);
        var stream = objFile.OpenRead();
        var objBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(objBytes, 5, (int)objFile.Length);
        HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(objBytes);
```